# LDAP Authentication - OpenShift - OKD

Tags: ldap, openshift, redhat, freeipa, okd

I have deployed a new OKD cluster (3.11) and as Identity Provider I have selected `LDAPPasswordIdentityProvider`

The configuration goes like this:

```
openshift_master_identity_providers=[{'name': 'idm', 'challenge': 'true', 'login': 'true', 'kind': 'LDAPPasswordIdentityProvider', 'attributes': {'id': ['dn'], 'email': ['mail'], 'name': ['cn'], 'preferredUsername': ['uid']}, 'bindDN': 'uid=service,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=myorg,dc=com', 'bindPassword': 'reallysecurepasswordhere', 'insecure': 'false', 'url': 'ldaps://idm.myorg.com:636/dc=myorg,dc=com?uid??(memberof=cn=openshift,cn=accounts,dc=myorg,dc=com)'}]
```

I have tried two dozens of possibilities with this URL.
On the logs I always get:

```
 I0528 15:23:38.491659       1 ldap.go:122] searching for (&(objectClass=*)(uid=user1))
 E0528 15:23:38.494172       1 login.go:174] Error authenticating "user1" with provider "idm": multiple entries found matching "user1"
```

I don't get it why is the filter showing as (&(objectClass=*)(uid=... appears as the filter isn't being parsed correctly, despite the URL being as above.
I also checked the master-config.yaml and it is correct as my ini file.

If I do ldapsearch I get the expected results:

```
$ ldapsearch -x -D "uid=service,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=myorg,dc=com" -W -H  ldaps://idm.myorg.com -s sub -b "cn=accounts,dc=myorg,dc=com" '(&(uid=user1)(memberof=cn=openshift,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=myorg,dc=com))' uid
Enter LDAP Password: 
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <cn=accounts,dc=myorg,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (&(uid=user1)(memberof=cn=openshift,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=myorg,dc=com))
# requesting: uid 
#

# user1, users, accounts, myorg.com
dn: uid=user1,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=myorg,dc=com
uid: user1

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

The LDAP Server is FreeIPA.

Help please!

Comment: Possibly the double `?` in your URL? `ldaps://idm.myorg.com:636/dc=myorg,dc=com?uid??(memberof=cn=openshift,cn=accounts,dc=myorg,dc=com)`

Maybe try `ldaps://idm.myorg.com:636/dc=myorg,dc=com?uid?(memberof=cn=openshift,cn=accounts,dc=myorg,dc=com)` or explicitly add `sub`, `ldaps://idm.myorg.com:636/dc=myorg,dc=com?uid?sub?(memberof=cn=openshift,cn=accounts,dc=myorg,dc=com)` You could also try restricting the `basedn` part of the URL, like `ldaps://idm.myorg.com:636/cn=openshift,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=myorg,dc=com?uid` and then remove the filter

Comment: Hi Will, thank you for your reply. I have tried them all actually, both with only one ? and with the explicit sub. both give the same result.
I also tried with the group on the basedn but I get in return no entries found.

I am now wondering when I run the openshift-ansible/playbooks/openshift-master/config.yml .... does this restart the master api ??? anyone? I was assuming it should, but now I am starting to think not

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution to the problem.

I assumed ... incorrectly ... that running the playbook `openshift-ansible/playbook/openshift-master/config.yml` would restart the openshift-master API.
It doesn't.

I noticed this when, instead of editing my ini inventory where I have this set and running config, I started editing directly on `/etc/origin/master/master-config.yaml` and using `master-restart api` to restart the API.
Several URL alterations (many incorrect actually) had never been ran. Config uploaded them, but the master api doesn't restart, so new config doesn't go in place, and I kept hitting the wall.